# mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I am trying to copy a file in Kubernetes to an existing directory. I am getting the error

`caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown`
I looked at similar issues, but cannot seem to resolve it. These are the confs

Configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: hdfs-yarn
data:
  yarn-site.xml: |
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    ...
```

This is my deployment yaml

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /opt/druid/conf/druid/cluster/_common/yarn-site.xml
      name: hdfs-volume
      subPath: yarn-site.xml
    - mountPath: /druid/data
      name: data-volume
...
volumes:
    - name: hdfs-volume
      configMap:
        name: hdfs-yarn
        items:
        - key: yarn-site.xml
          path: yarn-site.xml
...
```

Can anyone point out what could be wrong here? Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) states:

> Volumes can not mount onto other volumes or have hard links to other
> volumes

Instead of using one config map for volume hdf—--try using two config maps for each of the volems and let me know if this works.

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /opt/druid/conf/druid/cluster/_common/yarn-site.xml
      name: hdfs-volume
      subPath: yarn-site.xml
    - mountPath: /druid/data
      name: data-volume
...
volumes:
    - name: hdfs-volume
      configMap:
        name: hdfs-yarn
    - name: data-volume
      configMap:
        name:data-yarn
```

Refer this [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) and [Configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) doc for more information

Comment: This did not work. I actually have two different config map for the two volumes. The second volume is just for reference. The first one is the point of concern here